# Large gaps in the norm of a subgroup and its centraliser

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory

Take an infinite finitely generated group $G$ with an infinite subgroup $N$ which has an infinite centraliser $Z = Z_G(N)$. 
Let $S$ be some [symmetric] generating set of $G$ and for $g \in G$, 
denote by $\mathrm{norm}(g)$ the combinatorial distance between $g$ and the identity in the Cayley graph w.r.t. $S$.
Then $A= \mathrm{norm}(N)$ and $B=\mathrm{norm}(Z)$ are some subsets of the ($\geq 0$) integers.

**Question:** is it possible that $A$ and $B$ are asymptotically separated by large gaps, 
that is for every $C>1$ there is a $n_0$ such that

- $\forall a \in A \cap [n_0,\infty[$, $B \cap [a/C,aC] = \emptyset$
- $\forall b \in B \cap [n_0,\infty[$, $A \cap [b/C,bC] = \emptyset$

Note that if either $Z$ or $N$ contain an element $x$ of infinite order, 
then the answer is no (since $\mathrm{norm}(x^n) \to \infty$ and the triangle inequality implies $\mathrm{norm}(x^n) - \mathrm{norm}(x^{n-1}) \leq \mathrm{norm}(x)$, 
so the largest gap has length $< \mathrm{norm}(x)$).

This question is partially motivated by the fact that it is possible for the centre of an [infinite finitely generated] group $C = Z_G(G)$ to be so that $\mathrm{norm}(C)$ [is infinite] and has large gaps (in the sense that forall $C>1$ there is a $n > 2$ such that $\mathrm{norm}(C) \cap ]n/C,Cn[ = \emptyset$)

Comment: These conditions are trivially fulfilled if $N$ or $Z$ is finite. Also your argument that this is "no" if $Z$ or $N$ is not torsion also carries over the case when $Z$ or $N$ is locally finite. That is, your conditions imply that $Z$ and $N$ are locally finite.

Comment: You are right: I forgot to add the adjective "infinite" before $N$ and $Z_G(N)$.

Comment: Your remark on locally finiteness is essentially an "upgrade" on my remark on the fact that no element (of $N$ or $Z$) may have infinite order... or am I missing an important point?

Comment: I said "your argument... carries over". It's essentially the same argument but it yields a much stronger conclusion.

Comment: Thanks (i just was not sure if there was nonetheless a new ingredient required). So for eventual readers (which are as slow as I am): 
(1) If a subgroup $S$ is infinite, $\mathrm{norm}(S)$ is unbounded (because $G$ is fin.gen.) 
(2) In a fin. gen. subgroup, the norm of the generating elements bound the size of the gap (again by the triangle inequality) 
(3) Hence the $N$ and $Z$ [in the question] may not have infinite finitely generated subgroups (which is to say that they are locally finite)

Comment: For your question: first, I know finitely generated groups with a pair of infinite locally finite subgroups with your property (one can find such a pair in the lamplighter). But it's not a subgroup and its centralizer. I suspect an example how your require exists anyway, playing suitably with HNN extensions.

Comment: Thanks, I am quite sure such an example should exist, but I'm don't know how to build one (the example I mention at the end with $C= Z_G(G)$ having large gaps is quite convoluted). I'll try to look at HNN-extensions... (I assume the lamplighter subgroups are some parts of the lamp group? By that I mean $\oplus_{i_n} \mathbb{Z}_2$ (as a subgroup of $\oplus_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}_2$ with a well-chose sequence $\{i_n\} \subset \mathbb{Z}$).

Comment: Yes, in the lamplighter these are subgroups like this.